# A lot of "no such partition" questions, how do we clean them up?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

See this [Google Search for "no such partition" on Super User: 2700 (**224** according to the last page)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22no+such+partition%22&sitesearch=superuser.com%2Fquestions).

- [Without tag pages: 556 (**206** according to the last page)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22no+such+partition%22+-inurl:tagged&sitesearch=superuser.com%2Fquestions)
- [Without tag pages and close votes: 551 (**200** according to the last page)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22no+such+partition%22+-inurl%3atagged+-%22closed%20as%22&sitesearch=superuser.com%2Fquestions)

It would appear to me that most of these can be a duplicate of a more canonical question, rather have our site littered with a lot of different questions which makes it hard to find the different solutions.

Or even worse: Due to the amount of these questions, it becomes unfeasible to find a duplicate...

I think we need to clean this up similar like what we did with [our activation questions](https://superuser.com/questions/303136/windows-7-and-vista-activation-faq-how-do-language-version-64-bit-or-32-bit), what do you think?

Comment: That's a lot of results on Google!

Comment: @TomWijsman To see the **actual** number of results of a Google search, you have to skip to the last result page: http://blog.xkcd.com/2011/02/04/trochee-chart/

Comment: @TomWijsman Just five closed. Add `-"closed as"`.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Interesting read!

Comment: @OliverSalzburg: Updated the numbers, so we're down to 200. Still a lot.. :)